# Pruning displayed cells

Tags: filter, paraview

I have a dataset with particle traces as polylines (`vtkPolyData` with `vtkPoints` and `vtkCellArra`). I would like to display only some of the particle traces using a filter in Paraview, as they are sometimes too many; e.g. display only every 10th cell.

In the Glyph filter, there is are options to "Mask Points" (limit max number of displayed points) and "Random Mode" (pick displayed points randomly, not sequentially), so something similar.

Is there some ready-made filter for this, or if not, how to use the programmable filter to write one?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention cells, maybe you are interested in using the cell centers filter, that will convert all your cells to points (and the corresponding cell arrays to point arrays), so that you can apply the glyph to them.

For having more options in masking, you can apply the MaskPoints Filter before the glyph, and see if you can get the effect you want with all the options provided (for more options, look in the advanced properties by clicking the gear next to the search box).

Comment: The Glyph was only an example, I do want those cells to be displayed, but just not all of them, as they are too many.

Comment: the Mask Point filter is independent from the glyph filter... otherwise you can generate the ids and use some combination of python calculator(e.g modulus) and (scalar)clipping or thresholding